# Laravel: Task hasMany subtasks, each subtask can have many tasks , and no limit for that

Tags: laravel

I'm working with laravel 
I want to make a To-Do-List in the following way

Each Task (T) can have many subtasks (t1, t2, t3 .... etc), each one of these subtasks (ti) can have other subtasks (t1 can have subtasks which are t1a, t1b, t1c ... etc) , also each of these new subtasks can have many subtask (t1a can have subtasks t1a1, t1a2, t1a3 ... etc) and there is no limit for the depth of the task tree. is that thing possible ? And how to structure a MySQL database for that if it is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with just one table like so;

The CreateTasksTable class within /database/migrations folder:

```
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

In the App\Task model file you should create needed relations:

```
       public function parent()
       {
          return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id');
       }

       public function children()
       {
          return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
       }
```

And then, whenever you want to create a task it can be the parent of any number of tasks. And these child tasks also have their own child Tasks.

```
     $parent = App\Task::create(['name' => 'parentTask']);

     $child = App\Task::create(['name' => 'childTask', 'parent_id' => $parent->id]);

     $childOfChild = App\Task::create(['name' => '2xChild', 'parent_id' => $child->id]);
```

You can call the parent and children by typing their relation names:

```
     dd($parent->children); // get all children
     dd($child->parent); // get the parent
```

Have a good day :)